# Displaying background photos from array

Tags: javascript, html, background, photo

I am making a website with a table. Each cell should have it's own background image. I chose to put those images in an array. I made a function to create a  with the photo as background and the author as text. My code is under:

```js
var meme = [
'memes/0.jpg',
'memes/1.jpg',
'memes/2.jpg',
'memes/3.jpg',
'memes/4.jpg',
'memes/5.jpg',
'memes/6.jpg',
'memes/7.jpg',
'memes/8.jpg',
'memes/9.jpg',
'memes/10.jpg',
'memes/11.jpg'];

var author = [
'avelan',
'avelan',
'tjespe',
'tjespe',
'avelan',
'avelan',
'avelan',
'jakoo',
'avelan',
'avelan',
'email',
'email'];

function memeDisplay (i) {
for (i=0; i<meme.length; i++) {
    return ("<div class='meme' style='background-image:url(" + meme[i] + ")'>av " + author[i] + "</div>");
}
}
```

```css
body {
    margin:0px;
    background:#FFFFFF;
    background-image: url("jpg/dolan-wallpaper.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right bottom;
}
.header-cont {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
}
.header {
    height:100px;
    background:#303030;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-family: monaco;
    vertical-align: central;
    text-align:center;
}
.subheader {
    height:100px;
    background:#303030;
    border:1px solid #CCC;
    width:960px;
    margin: auto;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family:monaco;
    vertical-align: central;
    text-align:center;
}
.content {
    width:960px;
    background: #303030;
    border: 1px solid #CCC;
    margin: 70px auto;
}
.meme {
   width:300px; 
   height:300px; 
   background-position:center;
   margin:auto;
   font-family:monaco;
   vertical-align: text-bottom;
   text-align: right;
   color: white;
}
a {
    color:white
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <script type="text/javaScript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body style="background-image: url('jpg/dolan-wallpaper.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: right bottom;">
    
    <div class="header">
        Olans bæste memes
    </div><br><br><br>
    
    <div class="subheader"><br>
        Dette er vår offisielle nettside for memes. Her legger vi jevnlig ut asom memes til offentligheten. Vi lager omtrent alle selv. På hvert meme står det hvem som er forfatteren. Under ser du forhåndsvisninger av alle memesene vi har lagt ut. Bare trykk på de for å se hele bildet.
    </div>
    
    <div class="content">
        <table style="width:100%">
          <tr></tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="meme[0]"><script>memeDisplay(0)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[1]"><script>memeDisplay(1)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[2]"><script>memeDisplay(2)</script></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="meme[3]"><script>memeDisplay(3)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[4]"><script>memeDisplay(4)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[5]"><script>memeDisplay(5)</script></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="meme[6]"><script>memeDisplay(6)</script></a>
            <td><a href="meme[7]"><script>memeDisplay(7)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[8]"><script>memeDisplay(8)</script></a></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><a href="meme[9]"><script>memeDisplay(9)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[10]"><script>memeDisplay(10)</script></a></td>
            <td><a href="meme[11]"><script>memeDisplay(11)</script></a></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    
</body>
```

My problem is that when I visit the website nothing shows up in the table.
I would be very grateful if anyone could help me figure out what's wrong.

Comment: There are many things wrong in your code... That's not at all how JS works.

Comment: Reduce this down to the most basic problem, and take it from there. strip out all unnecessary html, css, js and array elements and the real problems will be staring you in the face.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is your code not working?

There are many things wrong with your code.

```
function memeDisplay (i) {
    for (i=0; i<meme.length; i++) {
        return ("..." + meme[i] + "..." + author[i] + "...");
    }
}
```

**The logic in your function**

First, your `memeDisplay` looks like you only want to display one meme with it, because you pass `i` as a parameter. If so, why do you use a `for` loop in there? Also, your loop resets `i` to `0`, so the parameter becomes useless.

**The `return` statement**

Then, `return` is used inside a function to stop the function and... return something. So, once again, the loop is useless, as only one iteration will happen (You `return` during the first iteration).

In short, your function actually always returns `"...memes/0.jpg...avelan..."`.

**Using the data returned by the function**

But for this returned value to be useful, you would have to use it. But right now, you just stuck some `<script>memeDisplay(0)</script>` in your HTML code. That's not how it works. JavaScript does not just print the value of a function where you use it in your HTML. It just executes it. You would need to do something like `document.write(memeDisplay(0))`, which does that. But once again, that's not the best way to do it.

## A possible solution

You can start by emptying your table. Just create an empty table, with an ID `myMemeTable`, that you can refer to in your JS.

Then, create a `displayMemes` function that will fill that table with all the memes, by using `insertRow` and `insertCell`, for example.

You can call it when the document is loaded, by using

`window.addEventListener('load', displayMemes, false);`

## Demo

Try it by clicking on the **Run code snippet** button below.

```js
var memes = [
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/0', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/1', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/2', author : 'tjespe' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/3', author : 'tjespe' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/4', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/5', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/6', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/7', author : 'jakoo'  },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/8', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/9', author : 'avelan' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/10', author : 'email' },
    { url : 'http://shrt.tf/img/cats/s/11', author : 'email' }
];

function displayMemes(){
    var table       = document.getElementById('myMemeTable'),
        CellsPerRow = 3,
        numOfMemes  = memes.length,
        numOfRows   = Math.ceil(numOfMemes/CellsPerRow);

    for(var i=0; i<numOfRows; i++){
        var row = table.insertRow();

        for(var j=0; j<CellsPerRow; j++){
            var cell      = row.insertCell(),
                memeIndex = i*CellsPerRow+j;
            if(memeIndex < numOfMemes){
                cell.innerHTML = "<a href='" + memes[memeIndex].url + "'>"
                               + "<div class='meme' style='background-image:url(" + memes[memeIndex].url + ")'>av "
                               + memes[memeIndex].author
                               + "</div>"
                               + "</a>";
            }
        }

    }
}

window.addEventListener('load', displayMemes, false);
```

```css
.meme {
   width:100px; 
   height:100px; 
   background-position:center;
   text-align: right;
   color: white;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%" id="myMemeTable">
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. This was very useful and I learned a lot as well. I am grateful for you taking your time to explain it so well.